# SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: No such host is known

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have been tring to connect to Sql Server from nodejs. But it is throwing an error. Here is my code connection code:

```
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

var config = {
    database : "chatbot",
    server : "LAPTOP-AR1H4E0R\SQLEXPRESS",
    driver:"msnodesqlv8",
    options:{
        // "instanceName":"SQLEXPRESS"
        trustedConnection:true
    }
};

mssql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("err", err)
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected")
    }
})
```

This is the error:

> ConnectionError: Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: No such host is known.
> ,Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired,Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
> at D:\Chatbot\agent-backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js:58:17
> at Immediate. (D:\Chatbot\agent-backend\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\connection.js:147:15)
> at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21) {
> code: undefined
> }

These are the connection credentials to the instance. It is working properly from the Management Studio.

[image]

Comment: `"LAPTOP-AR1H4E0R\\SQLEXPRESS"`, otherwise `\S` is interpreted as an escape sequence. Alternatively, use `instanceName`, but then specify the host only as `LAPTOP-AR1H4E0R`. *Alternatively*, specify the host but leave out the instance altogether -- if you have a default installation, the `SQLEXPRESS` instance will be running on the default port of 1433, and specifying an instance name is not required in that case.

Comment: Additional notes: when using an instance name the SQL Browser service must be running on the target server (and must have been restarted since any changes to SQL Server protocol configurations), and it must be accessible via Windows Firewall and network firewalls on udp/1434. If you already know the TCP port number that the instance is listening on prefer to use that directly instead of instance names - it reduces fragility.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

//create a database configuration 

var config = {

server : "your servername\\instancename", // eg:: DESKTOP_mjsi\\MSSQLEXPRESS'
databse: "your db name",

/* if using sql server authentication you need to provide user name & password else not required for                       window authentication */
  user :'sa',
 password:"your password",

options :{
 trustedConnection:true,
},
driver:"msnodesqlv8",

}
/*note: please make double ( \\ ) before your instance name
if you get confused then please watch the video link at the bottom you 
can see in details about this*/

// now make the connections as 

sql.connect(config,function(err){
if(err)conole.log(err)

// make a request as

var request = new sql.Request();

//make the query

var query = "your query goes here";  // eg : "select * from tbl_name"

request.query(query,funnction(err,records){
    if(err)console.log(err);
    else{
       console.log(records);
       //  your out put as records  
    }
 }

})
```

to know in more details please [follow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePi0HIz-6pE)